# How to manually set a cover in Musicbrainz Picard?

Tags: mp3, tags, id3, music-management

Is it possible to manually set a cover for a given MP3 file instead of letting the program automatically fetching it from the web?

I have noticed that I can alter every other field to my liking before saving the tags to file, but I can't manage to set a custom cover.

If it makes any difference, I'm using the Linux version on openSUSE 13.2.

Comment: Have you seen this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84915/add-album-art-cover-to-mp3-ogg-file-from-command-line-in-batch-mode ?

Comment: So you might want to have different cover art for songs from the same album?

Comment: No, I just want to manually set it instead of letting the program doing it automatically. I don't necessarily need a different cover for every file

Comment: Have you seen [this documentation](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/How_to_Add_Cover_Art)?

Comment: Thanks but I want to add covers to my files, not to the site database

Answer (score 5):

I just found a workaround: you can go to "Options...", "Cover Art", then uncheck **all** coverart providers from the list, and click OK. Now you can still autotag the audio files, but Picard will not download any cover picture; from now on, you can drag and drop your own cover picture to the little black square on the bottom right corner (the one with a CD icon on it), then hit CTRL+S to save.
It's not very practical, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom artwork by dragging and dropping an image file (preferable JPEG or PNG, but I think TIFF and GIF would work, too) to the cover art box.

This is a somewhat hidden option. Proper custom cover art support for Picard has been requested for a while, but so far nobody really took up the task.

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work; when I save the files, the program doesn't keep this change, and retains the downloaded cover.

Comment: While this works, image can't be applied to cluster and has to be separately added to every track.